# How to Replace a File text with another file text in java

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have two files. I want to replace first file content with other file content

one contains

```
<Test>
<Test>56596</Test>
<PMt>851</PMt>
</H>
<Test>5659556</Test>
<H>
<Test>56556</Test>
<PMt>781</PMt>
</H>
<Test>5659556</Test>
</Test>
```

Second Contains:

```
<PMt>1</PMt>
<PMt>2</PMt>
<PMt>3</PMt>
```

Output File:

```
<Test>
<Test>56596</Test>
<PMt>1</PMt>
</H>
<Test>5659556</Test>
<H>
<Test>56556</Test>
<PMt>2</PMt>
</H>
<Test>5659556</Test>
<PMt>3</PMt>
</Test>
```

I am trying following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReplaceText {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputFile = "C:\\Files\\File1.txt";
        //String outputFile = "C:\\Files\\output.txt";
        List<String> searchList = new ArrayList<>();
        searchList.add("<PMt>(.+?)</PMt>");
        searchList.add("<PMt>(.+?)</PMt>");
        List<String> replaceList = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean[] replaced = new boolean[searchList.size()];

        // Read text to replace with from another file
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Files\\File2.txt"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                replaceList.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Read input file and replace text
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(inputFile)) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < searchList.size(); i++) {
                    if (!replaced[i]) {
                        String search = searchList.get(i);
                        int index = line.indexOf(search);
                        if (index != -1) {
                            line = line.substring(0, index) + replaceList.get(i) + line.substring(index + search.length());
                            replaced[i] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                fw.write(line + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this but it giving me same file again in output

Comment: This looks like a job for XSLT.

Comment: You can't read from and write to the same file at the same time. Write to a temporary file, then delete the original and rename.

Answer (score 0):

Your searchList contains regular expressions; `indexOf` does a raw search, it does not interpret its argument as a regular expression. You presumably want something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(searchList.get(i));
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
... and so on ...
```

Comment: It work for regular expression

Comment: @AliMurtza No it doesn't. Your RE must have matched as a raw string.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm seems to be fairly straightforward. Apart from the two input files, you need to create an output file. You read file *File1.txt*, line by line. If the line matches a line that you want to change, e.g.

```
<PMt>851</PMt>
```

then you read a line from *File2.txt* and write it to the output file. In every other case, you write the line that you just read from *File1* to the output file.

Note that the below code is not generic, it handles exactly the sample input and expected output as posted in your question. Hence the [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) checks for a line that starts with `<PMt>` and ends with `</PMt>` and in between contains only digits and at least one digit. The code also uses [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class RplceTxt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path1 = Paths.get("file1.txt");
        Path path2 = Paths.get("file2.txt");
        Path outpath = Paths.get("result.txt");
        try (BufferedReader reader1 = Files.newBufferedReader(path1);
             BufferedReader reader2 = Files.newBufferedReader(path2);
             BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outpath,
                                                             StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                             StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
            String line1 = reader1.readLine();
            String line2 = reader2.readLine();
            while (line1 != null) {
                if (line1.matches("^<PMt>\\d+</PMt>$")) {
                    if (line2 != null) {
                        writer.write(line2);
                        line2 = reader2.readLine();
                    }
                    else {
                        writer.write(line1);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    writer.write(line1);
                }
                writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
                line1 = reader1.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of the output file (i.e. *result.txt*):

```
<Test>
<Test>56596</Test>
<PMt>1</PMt>
</H>
<Test>5659556</Test>
<H>
<Test>56556</Test>
<PMt>2</PMt>
</H>
<Test>5659556</Test>
</Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create a logic with replace a string in the file. You can do it lazy by reading line by line from the source file and in case line was updated, read next line from the pattern file.

I think it's better to encapsulate replace logic for an individual string with separate class, because replacement can be not a trivial task.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class PatternData {

    private static final PatternData NULL = new PatternData(null, null, null);

    private final String prefix;
    private final String suffix;
    private final String value;

    public static PatternData create(String str) {
        if (str == null)
            return NULL;

        int lo = str.indexOf('>') + 1;
        int hi = str.indexOf('<', lo + 1);

        return new PatternData(str.substring(0, lo),
                               str.substring(hi),
                               str.substring(lo, hi));
    }

    public Optional<String> replace(String str) {
        int lo = this == NULL ? -1 : str.indexOf(prefix);
        int hi = lo > -1 ? str.indexOf(suffix, lo + 1) : -1;

        return hi == -1 ? Optional.empty()
                        : Optional.of(str.substring(0, lo + prefix.length())
                                    + value + str.substring(hi));
    }

}
```

Then you're ready to build a replacement logic of the file.

```java
public static void replacePattern(Path srcFile, Path patternFile, Path dstFile)
                         throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(srcFile);
         BufferedReader patternIn = Files.newBufferedReader(patternFile);
         BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(dstFile,
                                                 StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                 StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {

        String str;
        PatternData patternData = PatternData.create(patternIn.readLine());

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Optional<String> res = patternData.replace(str);

            if (res.isPresent()) {
                str = res.get();
                patternData = PatternData.create(patternIn.readLine());
            }

            out.write(str);
            out.write(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, in case you want to replace an original file, you cannot do it at the same time. You have to create a temporary file, fill it and then replace original one the temporary result.

```java
public static void replacePattern(Path srcFile, Path patternFile) throws IOException {
    Path tmpFile = srcFile.getParent().resolve(srcFile.getFileName() + ".tmp");
    Files.deleteIfExists(tmpFile);
    replacePattern(srcFile, patternFile, tmpFile);
    Files.move(tmpFile, srcFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    Files.deleteIfExists(tmpFile);
}
```

The client could be look like this:

```java
Path srcFile = Path.of("c:/File1.txt");
Path patternFile = Path.of("c:/File2.txt");
replacePattern(srcFile, patternFile);
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you're attempting to open a `FileWriter` on `inputFile`, when you currently have a `FileReader` object open.

Around lines 30 and 31.

```java
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(inputFile))
```

I believe you want to change the `FileWriter` argument to `outputFile`.

Secondly, the parameters are not defined, in terms of when and where to place a `PMt` element within the `File1.txt` text.
For example.

```xml
<Test>
<Test>56596</Test>
<PMt>1</PMt>
</H>
<Test>5659556</Test> <-- does not have a PMt element
<H>
<Test>56556</Test>
<PMt>2</PMt>
</H>
<Test>5659556</Test> <-- does have a PMt element
<PMt>3</PMt>
</Test>
```